# leaflet map in shiny

Tags: r, shiny, leaflet

I am new to shiny and try to pull up my map (which will eventually, be clickable to show data stored for particular sa4_code_2016 areas)

The code i have works well alone, but in shiny it does not show errors, but does not show the map....

i load my file in global.r and then my ui.r looks like this:

```
sliderInput(
                               'year_vic',
                               label=("Select year"), min = 2025, max = 2051,
                               value = c(2030),
                               sep="",
                               step=1
                               ),
leafletOutput("map_vic")
```

and then my server.r looks like this:

```
   map_df = reactive({

     shape_data %>%
       filter(year==input$year_vic[1]) %>%

       left_join(absmapsdata::sa42016)%>%
       st_as_sf(sf_column_name="geometry")

   })


   output$map_vic <- renderLeaflet({
     leaflet() %>%
       addTiles() %>%
       addPolygons(data=map_df, weight = 2, fillColor = "yellow")


   })
```

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: `data = map_df()`, with parentheses.

Comment: LOL at myself! LOVE you dearly! :)